# jQuery picklist

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf

I used this [jQuery picklist](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/)

```
$(function()
{
    $("#selectUsers").pickList();
});
```

and in jsf page

```
<h:selectManyMenu id="selectUsers">
      <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

in Java

```
private List<SelectItem> selectItems;
```

How can I get users that I selected in picklist in Java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `value=#{someBean.myValue}` in `h:selectManyMenu` and define `myValue` as List `List<String> myValue`

Code will be as below.

### JSF

```
                                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
<h:selectManyMenu id="selectUsers" value="#{someBean.myValue}"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

### Java

```
List<String> myValue;
// setter and getter
```

### Edit 1

I noticed that you want list as Dual list. For that I would suggest you to use [**Primefaces picklist**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf). You will not need to write much code. See second option, its just awesome.

Comment: @Classico : Any update on above question? What and where its not working for more then 400 item?

Comment: I incorrectly explained, it's work with the fixed number of items. And of course you can expand it. In my case it's not good. Or may be i have not got enough experience in primefaces) because I'm just learning)

Comment: @Classico : Could you edit your question and let us know what cases are not working? I am using Primefaces and its wonderful.

Comment: @Classico : Better you edit the question and explain what is working and what is going wrong. Then we might help you.

Comment: hmm... I tried to used primefaces picklist and now it's work fine.I was wrong about it. i have problem with my db and that's why it worked bad. thx for help.))